# Why does omitting variable in for cycle in PowerShell results in an endless loop?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Why does

```
 $i=1
 for ($i -le 5; $i++)
 {Write-Host $i}
```

result in an infinite loop?
I never tried to write something like this in C# or any other programming language, so I don't know how it will behave there, but why would the for cycle not just grab the  "i" variable compare it to 5, add 1 to it and compare it again, it's like the for cycle is blind or some form of a machine, instead of a reasonable, logical human being.

Why infinite and not just grab predefined i?
Answers like "because that's how PowerShell functions" are useless, I want to know **why** it works like that.

I know it becomes infinite, because it's missing the first parameter, I want to know **why**, though, like the answer the the philosophical "why would the for cycle not look for the variable of the same name outside of its cycle, but must be specifically included in it?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the Windows PowerShell language specifications, you'll see this grammar for the for statement:

```
for-statement:
for   new-linesopt   (
        new-linesopt   for-initializeropt   statement-terminator
        new-linesopt   for-conditionopt   statement-terminator
        new-linesopt   for-iteratoropt
        new-linesopt   )   statement-block
for   new-linesopt   (
        new-linesopt   for-initializeropt   statement-terminator
        new-linesopt   for-conditionopt
        new-linesopt   )   statement-block
for   new-linesopt   (
        new-linesopt   for-initializeropt
        new-linesopt   )   statement-block
for-initializer:
pipeline
for-condition:
pipeline
for-iterator:
pipeline
```

Meaning that in your example, **the first statement is the INITIALIZER**.

If you rewrite your loop this way:

```
$i=1
for (;$i -le 5; $i++)
{Write-Host $i}
```

it will work as you expect. **Note the additional ";".**

If you omit the ";", in the grammar above `$i++` corresponds to the **for-condition** which constantly evaluates to $true, so the loop never ends.

Comment: @mathgenius It seems you misunderstood the answer. It's not because it doesn't use variable outside the `for-block`, but it's because `$i -le 5` becomes the initializer (though I don't know what happens), and `$i++` becomes the checking condition (which always evaluate to true, according to the answer), **leaving the third parameter empty** (no iterator, though `i` is incremented in checking condition).

Answer (score 1):

In your edit, you say you know it becomes infinite, but you want to know WHY.
The answer, is that PowerShell does, automatically, type conversion.

You start with an `int` type with a value of 1, which is incremented. When it reaches `[int]::MaxValue` and is incremented by 1, the type `int` cannot hold this value anymore. Then, PowerShell converts its type, automatically, to `double`. For instance, try this:

```
$i=[int]::MaxValue -2

++$i
$i.GetType()

++$i
$i.GetType()

++$i
$i.GetType()

++$i
$i.GetType()
```

Look at the output, and see PowerShell converts the type from `int` to a `double`.

The maximum value of a `double` incremented by 1 is equals to itself, thus, the loop will never end.